# In MS Access VBA, is there something wrong with this many quotes?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

The data and code below are boiled down from a large, complex project to just show one particular issue.

Consider the sample table `tTest`:

[image]

I need to find duplicates in the data as follows:

- `NumData` = `iif(WhichNum = "A", NumData1, NumData2)`
- Look for duplicates in `NumData` and `TextData`.

You can see that the data for `ID` = 2 and 4 are duplicates by those criteria because they have `NumData` = 4 and `TextData` = "text2".

I want a query to detect such duplicates. But Access is notoriously bad in its handling of the SQL code of stored queries, removing all line breaks and most spaces, so that the code of the query become very difficult to read. For this reason, when I have a complex query, I write its code in VBA, where my line breaks and spaces are preserved, and then store and open the query from VBA. Afterwards, the query can be opened from the query list in Access without VBA, but changes are maintained in VBA, where the code can be read most easily.

My query to find these duplicates defines `NumData` and then counts the occurrences of pairs of `NumData` and `TextData`. The count cannot be done in a subquery because `NumData` is a field alias and a field alias cannot be used in the same select statement in which it is defined.

Although I can't use a subquery, I have a function that can perform the task of a subquery, but allowing the use of a field alias:

```vb
Function vFtnInQry(sField As String, sSQL As String) As Variant
' Return the value of the field with the name <sField> in the select query <sSQL>.
' The purpose of this is to allow inserting a variable value into the SQL of a query.

Dim oRecSet As DAO.Recordset, nCountRecords As Long, vRetVal As Variant

Set oRecSet = CurrentDb().OpenRecordset(sSQL)
nCountRecords = oRecSet.RecordCount
If (nCountRecords = 0) Then
    vRetVal = Null
  Else
    vRetVal = oRecSet.Fields(sField).Value
  End If

vFtnInQry = vRetVal

End Function    ' vFtnInQry()
```

With that, I can write my query:

```
Sub qMakeQuery_bad()

Dim oCurDb As DAO.Database, oQuery As QueryDef, sSQL As String
sSQL = _
    "SELECT " & _
        "ID, " & _
        "iif([WhichNum] = ""A"", NumData1, NumData2) AS [NumData], " & _
        "vFtnInQry(""sCount"", ""SELECT count(*) AS sCount FROM tTest " & _
            "WHERE (iif([WhichNum] = """"A"""", NumData1, NumData2) = "" & [NumData] & "") and " & _
                  "([TextData] = """""" & [TextData] & """""") "") " & _
            "AS CountThisOne " & _
    "FROM tTest;"

Set oCurDb = CurrentDb()
Set oQuery = oCurDb.CreateQueryDef("qTest")
oQuery.SQL = sSQL
oQuery.Close
Set oQuery = Nothing
Set oCurDb = Nothing
DoCmd.OpenQuery ("qTest")

End Sub     ' qMakeQuery_bad()
```

The field alias `NumData` is defined in the line:

```
"iif([WhichNum] = ""A"", NumData1, NumData2) AS [NumData], "
```

and it is referred to in the condition:

```
iif([WhichNum] = """"A"""", NumData1, NumData2) = "" & [NumData] & ""
```

But the name of the query has the suffix "bad" because the query chokes on `ID` = 3 with the error:

- Run-time error '3075': Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '(iif([WhichNum] = "A", NumDatal, NumData2) = 5) and ([TextData] = "text"3"")'.

because of the quotation marks in `text"3"`.

To handle this, I have to double those quotation marks before the query evaluates the data. I do this with a call to `replace()`:

```vb
Sub qMakeQuery()

Dim oCurDb As DAO.Database, oQuery As QueryDef, sSQL As String
sSQL = _
    "SELECT " & _
        "ID, " & _
        "iif([WhichNum] = ""A"", NumData1, NumData2) AS [NumData], " & _
        "vFtnInQry(""sCount"", ""SELECT count(*) AS sCount FROM tTest " & _
            "WHERE (iif([WhichNum] = """"A"""", NumData1, NumData2) = "" & [NumData] & "") and " & _
                  "([TextData] = """""" & replace([TextData], """""""", """""""""""") & """""") "") " & _
            "AS CountThisOne " & _
    "FROM tTest;"

Set oCurDb = CurrentDb()
Set oQuery = oCurDb.CreateQueryDef("qTest")
oQuery.SQL = sSQL
oQuery.Close
Set oQuery = Nothing
Set oCurDb = Nothing
DoCmd.OpenQuery ("qTest")

End Sub     ' qMakeQuery()
```

This query runs without error and gives me the correct counts:

[image]

but the string of 12 quotes in the third argument of `replace()` looks pretty ridiculous. That makes me wonder if I've gone down a wrong road somewhere and should have done something differently.

Comment: But it works!! Try using Chr(34) instead of escaping quote mark. `Replace([TextData], Chr(34), Chr(34) & Chr(34))`.

Comment: The `chr(34)`s are a neat trick that eliminated all the `"`s in those arguments, the longest strings of `"`s, and leave the code working just as before. If you post that suggestion as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Consider a stored query from the outset and avoid mixing SQL with VBA, especially since you do use any VBA variables. Stored queries can call VBA functions which can be avoided with a subquery and Access' `DCount` domain aggregate.

```sql
SELECT 
  *,
  DCount(
    "*", 
    "tTest", 
    "IIF([WhichNum] = 'A', NumData1, NumData2) = " & NumData &
    "    AND TextData = '" & TextData & "'"
  ) AS DupCount
FROM (
  SELECT
    ID, 
    IIF([WhichNum] = 'A', NumData1, NumData2) AS [NumData],
    NumData1,
    NumData2,
    TextData
  FROM tTest
) sub
```

Comment: I've edited the question to explain why I use VBA to write the code of the query. You've provided nicely formatted SQL in your answer, and you suggest entering that without using VBA. But if I enter that SQL into a query design window, Access will remove the line breaks and most spaces to reduce it to a mass of text that is very difficult to read. Do you know a way, other than writing it in VBA, to store this code in Access with its line breaks and spaces preserved?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no text formatting in Access SQL editor (yet?) which is an often requested feature by users. For complex queries, I save its text in external .sql files (good for backup/version control). I even read complex queries directly from .sql files in VBA. I always avoid mixing VBA with SQL which gets messy as you are encountering with quotes and concatenation.

Comment: BTW - in Access, stored queries are more efficient than VBA string SQL run on the fly since DB engine saves best execution plan and caches stats!

Comment: Re your second comment, as you see in the code, I have VBA store the query, so after it's created, I can open it from the query list in Access. That has the efficiency you're talking about, right?

Comment: Possibly, but you are building it on the fly then immediately calling it. And your SQL can contain syntax or runtime errors. Using query design, no saved query can have errors. Stats update when query is compiled or database is compacted and maybe not just when its SQL changes.

Comment: Actually, you do not release the querydef before running it with `DoCmd.OpenQuery`, so your run uses its last saved instance! Incorporate this `DCount` solution using single quotes for `IIF` and move `OpenQuery` to very end.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a summary of what I got from the comment from @June7 and the answer from @Parfait.

It doesn't seem that I was doing anything wrong, but there was an easy way to eliminate the longest strings of quotes by replacing them with `chr(34)`s, as suggested by @June7.

I tried to make the code more readable by replacing those `chr(34)`s with either a const or a variable, but neither worked. See code below for details. (If someone can explain why neither worked, that would be appreciated.)

@Parfait's code included some changes of pairs of double quotes to single quotes, which improved things a bit. But his code did not address the main problem because it omitted the call to `replace()`, which contained the longest strings of `"`s.

@Parfait's code did make an unrelated suggestion of using `dCount()` to do the count instead of my UDF. I implemented that with some code to offer the choice of counting method. When I tested it on a query of 300,000 rows, I found that both displayed the datasheet in about the same amount of time. (However, an [answer to another question I posted about how to measure the time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76396500/in-ms-access-vba-how-to-measure-the-time-to-display-a-query/#76397293) pointed out that the display time is not really relevant to the time to actually calculate the query, and I need to understand that better.)

Those changes are combined in the following revision of `qMakeQuery()`, which is tested and works:

```
Sub qMakeQuery_2()

' New version of qMakeQuery() with these changes:
'   * Change second and third arguments of replace() to use chr(34) instead of long stinrgs of double quotes.
'   * Change two double quotes to one single quote in:
'       Change from:                                To:
'           vFtnInQry(""sCount"",                       vFtnInQry('sCount',
'           "iif([WhichNum] = ""A"",                    iif([WhichNum] = 'A',
'           "WHERE (iif([WhichNum] = """"A"""",         "WHERE (iif([WhichNum] = 'A',
'       Was not able to make this change on other pairs of double quotes either because:
'           * SQL needed them to interpret as one double quote, or
'           * The substitution doesn't seem to work across a line break, such as on ""SELECT ...
'   * Allow user choice of vFtnInQry() or dCount() to count duplicates.

' It works with all these changes, so I'm implementing them in the project.
'   When implemented in query with 300,000 rows, time to display datasheet about the same for vFtnInQry() and dCount().

' c_quot and sQuot were made to take the place of chr(34) in the call to replace().
'   But using either one results in dialog box, "Enter parameter value" for it.
Const c_quot As String = """": Const c_2quots As String = """"""
Dim sQuot As String: sQuot = Chr(34)

Dim oCurDb As DAO.Database, oQuery As QueryDef, sSQL As String

Dim sMethod As String, sSQLcount As String
sMethod = IIf(InputBox("Method: A for FtnInQry or B for dCount", , "A") = "A", "FtnInQry", "dCount")
Select Case sMethod
    Case "FtnInQry": sSQLcount = _
        "vFtnInQry('sCount', ""SELECT count(*) AS sCount FROM tTest " & _
            "WHERE (iif([WhichNum] = 'A', NumData1, NumData2) = "" & [NumData] & "") and " & _
                  "([TextData] = """""" & replace([TextData], Chr(34), Chr(34) & Chr(34)) & """""") "") "
    Case "dCount": sSQLcount = _
        "dCount('*', 'tTest', " & _
            """(iif([WhichNum] = 'A', NumData1, NumData2) = "" & [NumData] & "") and " & _
              "([TextData] = """""" & replace([TextData], Chr(34), Chr(34) & Chr(34)) & """""") "") "
  End Select

sSQL = _
    "SELECT " & _
        "ID, " & _
        "iif([WhichNum] = 'A', NumData1, NumData2) AS [NumData], " & _
        sSQLcount & "AS CountThisOne " & _
    "FROM tTest;"

Set oCurDb = CurrentDb()
Set oQuery = oCurDb.CreateQueryDef("qTest")
oQuery.SQL = sSQL
oQuery.Close
Set oQuery = Nothing
Set oCurDb = Nothing
DoCmd.OpenQuery ("qTest")

End Sub     ' qMakeQuery_2()
```

@Parfait's code also suggested moving the definition of `NumData` from the SELECT statement to a subquery in the FROM statement. This change is implemented in the following code. It works, but as stated in the comments, I don't see the advantage, and so am not implementing this change in my project. If there is an advantage to doing this, please explain.

```
Sub qMakeQuery_3()

' New version of qMakeQuery() with definition of [NumData] moved from SELECT statement to subquery in FROM statement.
'   It works with this change, but I don't see the advantage of it, so I'm not implementing it.

Dim oCurDb As DAO.Database, oQuery As QueryDef, sSQL As String
sSQL = _
    "SELECT " & _
        "ID, " & _
        "[NumData], " & _
        "vFtnInQry(""sCount"", ""SELECT count(*) AS sCount FROM tTest " & _
            "WHERE (iif([WhichNum] = """"A"""", NumData1, NumData2) = "" & [NumData] & "") and " & _
                  "([TextData] = """""" & replace([TextData], """""""", """""""""""") & """""") "") " & _
            "AS CountThisOne " & _
    "FROM (SELECT ID, iif([WhichNum] = ""A"", NumData1, NumData2) AS [NumData], NumData1, NumData2, TextData " & _
            "FROM tTest);"

Set oCurDb = CurrentDb()
Set oQuery = oCurDb.CreateQueryDef("qTest")
oQuery.SQL = sSQL
oQuery.Close
Set oQuery = Nothing
Set oCurDb = Nothing
DoCmd.OpenQuery ("qTest")

End Sub     ' qMakeQuery_3()
```

Comment: Ah, yes. Thank you. Both code segments in both question and my answer edited with that correction. Revisions tested and work correctly.

Comment: Regarding used of constant/variable for quote mark as opposed to Chr(34), I would like to see a Debug.Print of constructed SQL statement for each case.

Comment: @June7 - In `qMakeQuery_2()`, changing six `chr(34)` to `c_quot` and at the prompt selecting "B" for `dCount()`, I get the additional prompt for "Enter parameter value", and the SQL is `SELECT ID, iif([WhichNum] = 'A', NumData1, NumData2) AS [NumData], dCount('*', 'tTest', "(iif([WhichNum] = 'A', NumData1, NumData2) = " & [NumData] & ") and ([TextData] = """ & replace([TextData], c_quot, c_quot & c_quot) & """) ") AS CountThisOne FROM tTest;`.

Comment: If that is the Debug output of SQL string, then the imbedded c_quot constant won't work. The SQL engine doesn't know what that is so it fails when actually tries to open query - cannot evaluate VBA custom constants and global variables although can process TempVars. However, it does recognize Chr(34) function and can evaluate.