# In MS Access VBA, how to measure the time to display a query?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I want to measure the time that it takes to run and display a query. It appears that there are three different lengths of time:

A. The time between VBA opening the query and control returning to the next VBA line. This can be measured by:

```
dTime = Evaluate("Now()")
DoCmd.OpenQuery (sQueryName)
MsgBox (((Evaluate("Now()") - dTime) * 86400) & " seconds")
```

But this is not the whole time that it takes to calculate the datasheet. After the message box appears from the above code, for a large query, the datasheet window may still be mostly empty, waiting for its contents to be drawn.

B. The time between opening the query and when the datasheet is fully drawn.

Even this appears to not be the whole time to complete work on the query because, for a large query, when the datasheet is fully drawn, it still does not respond to a mouse click to select it.

C. The time between opening the query and its datasheet responding to a mouse click to select it.

In a query that I'm currently working on with 300,000 rows, the times are approximately:

- A. 0.1 seconds
- B. 9 seconds
- C. 17 seconds

The time `A` is as reported in the message box, and so is exact. But `B` and `C` are counted manually by me watching the behavior of the datasheet window. I don't know if there is a way to programmatically detect the completion of `B` and `C` so that I could have those times accurately.

Even `C` is not the time to calculate all the rows of the query. At the end of `C`, scrolling the datasheet window can take another long time for the sheet to be redrawn. On my current query of 300,000 rows, this is about another 9 seconds, after which the datasheet is fully redrawn and responds to a mouse click to select it. I suppose this delay for scrolling means that each time, only the visible part of the datasheet is fully calculated.

I want to measure the speed-effect of a change in the code of the query, so it would be helpful to have an accurate measure of `B` and/or `C`. Is there a way to get that?

Comment: Evaluate() function is not necessary - don't put Now() within quote marks. With a large dataset, not all records are retrieved at once - additional records will be loaded to memory when scrolling. Try opening a recordset of table and move to EOF. Why is it important to know how quick query opens? Users should not interact with tables or queries.

Comment: @June7 - Re `evaluate()`: For reasons I don't know, `now()` on its own reports only whole seconds, but `evaluate("now()")` reports in millisecs. Requires reference to Excel object library. Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470632/vba-show-clock-time-with-accuracy-of-less-than-a-second/#39019601

Comment: If you want to get a good idea of timings execute the benchmark 10 times and divide by 10. This will also give you an idea of the variation of execution times.

Comment: @June7 - Re queries: I am my own and only user. I don't need the added complexity of forms and reports, so I work in queries. Why do I care how long they take? I'd prefer not to wait 17 seconds every time I run it if I don't have to.

Comment: Okay, learned something new about Now(). How would you reduce the load time?

Comment: @June7 - I don't understand your question about load time.

Comment: If you don't want to wait 17 seconds, what would you do to reduce this wait?

Comment: I want to test the differences between running `dCount()` and running a UDF I wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Timer, it is close enough:

```vb
Dim StartTime As Double

StartTime = Timer
DoCmd.OpenQuery (sQueryName)
DoEvents
MsgBox CStr(Timer - StartTime) & " seconds"
```

Comment: I don't quite understand how that works, but it appears to be giving me `B`. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

So, introduction of a asynchronous view that can display partial results then is going to tell you NOTHING of much value here.

You will wind up testing the UI response, and that will have little to do with the speed of the query, and if you are to determine if that query runs faster, or slower.

So, for sure, always make sure option explicit is turned on - ALWAYS!!!!

If you want to test/benchmark the speed of a query, then of course trying to open a query as a datasheet? As I stated, that's not going to tell you much of anything at all here.

So, if you want to test the speed of the database data pull? Then write some test code, and DUMP use of interaction and UI elements.

You could say AFTER testing and determining the speed of the query, consider some extra testing in regards to how well the "display" part works, but as a general rule, having a mumble jumble of trying to display query results on the screen and that of how fast the query runs are two VERY HUGE LARGE VAST different things to test.

So, here is some code that gives some workable approach.

So, dump this code in a newly created module. Save the module, and then from the immediate window you can run that code (you can even place the cursor in the code stub, and hit f5, or as noted, use the command line and type in that sub name.

So, this code:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

    Sub QueryTest()
    
        Dim rstData         As DAO.Recordset
        Dim strSQL          As String
        Dim TimeStart       As Double
        Dim TimeTotal       As Double
        Dim RowCount        As Long
        
        strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblbig"
        
        TimeStart = Timer
        
        ' run the query
        
        Set rstData = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
        rstData.MoveLast    ' force pulling of all data into recordset
        RowCount = rstData.RecordCount
        rstData.Close
        
        TimeTotal = Timer - TimeStart
        
        Debug.Print "Time to run SQL (seconds) = " & TimeTotal & "   Rows = " & RowCount
        
        
        strSQL = "SELECT City, Count(*) as MyCount FROM tblbig GROUP BY City"
            
        TimeStart = Timer
        Set rstData = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
            
        rstData.MoveLast
        RowCount = rstData.RecordCount
        rstData.Close
        
        TimeTotal = Timer - TimeStart
        Debug.Print "Time to run group by SQL (seconds) = " & TimeTotal & "   Rows = " & RowCount
        
            
    End Sub
```

So, to run this code, I do this:

[image]

In the case of the UI, you often wind up testing how fast the user can scroll or page the data - so leave that for the 2nd round of testing.

A good way to test speed of the query (the speed of the data engine), is to NOT open the query to the UI, but do this in code, and thus we remove the UI part.

So, the above should at least give you an idea of how a query change effects speed.

You can also of course do the above against existing queries, since it would not make sense to re-type all your existing sql from existing queries.

```
        strSQL = "qryCity"
        TimeStart = Timer
        Set rstData = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
            
        rstData.MoveLast
        RowCount = rstData.RecordCount
        rstData.Close
        
        TimeTotal = Timer - TimeStart
        Debug.Print "Time to run qryCity (seconds) = " & TimeTotal & "   Rows = " & RowCount
```

Comment: That's a lot of interesting and valuable instruction, which will take some time for me to understand well enough to implement. I think it will be very important to understand the difference between the processing time for calculation and for display, which I think is what you're explaining.

Comment: yes, you much want to keep the 2 issues separate, since then you wind up not really testing the data pull. So, create a module, put in some test code. You can quite much use that bit of code over and over - get some good ideas as to this or that sql runs slower, or faster. Using a openquery not going to help, since it does not automatic pull all the data - it only tries to fill the display, and thus you not really get a good indication of query speed, but again, you get more of a display speed issue. Even a larger monitor will display more rows - you get different results as a result.